# Set different font sizes with imagettftext()

Tags: php, font-size, imagettftext

Is it possible to set different `font-size`s on the images within one `imagettftext()`?

I have managed to output the needed text on the image. Now, I want to show the `$subheadliner_thu_1` in larger `font-size`. I don't want to put it in a new `imagettftext()`, because the length of the text could change in the future. So, set coordinates should not be used for `$undercard_thu_4`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img/pkp-empty.jpg');
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
  $font_path = 'fonts/calibri.ttf';

  $undercard_thu_1 = "amelie lens";
  $undercard_thu_1 = strtoupper($undercard_thu_1);
  $undercard_thu_2 = "beautifull swimmers";
  $undercard_thu_2 = strtoupper($undercard_thu_2);
  $undercard_thu_4 = "cypress hill";
  $undercard_thu_4 = strtoupper($undercard_thu_4);
  $subheadliner_thu_1 = "chance the rapper";
  $subheadliner_thu_1 = strtoupper($subheadliner_thu_1);

  $lineup_upper1 = $undercard_thu_1 . ' • ' . $undercard_thu_2;
  $lineup1 = wordwrap($lineup_upper1, 60, "\n", false);

  $lineup_upper2 = $subheadliner_thu_1 . ' • ' . $undercard_thu_4;
  $lineup2 = wordwrap($lineup_upper2, 60, "\n", false);

  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 295, 532, $white, $font_path, $lineup1);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 72, 579, $white, $font_path, $lineup2);

  imagejpeg($jpg_image);
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: If you are using a fixed width font, it's easy to create a function that can calculate the widths, otherwise you might have issues

Comment: I don't think you can... especially considering what @delboy1978uk said...

Comment: I made a PDF thing, and some lines I had to calculate widths etc. Have a look here and CTRL-F  for `fitting text to a specific width` for an idea of how you might code this. https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/zend_pdf-with-templates/